# Is the sentence considered one independent sentence or two independent sentences?

Tags: grammar

We can return or exchange the purchased items.

I have a question.  Is the sentence above considered one independent sentence or two independent sentences?   I think it is one indenpendent sentence.  (I am not talking about as for a clause but as for an independent sentence)

Could you help me clarify it?   Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not 100% clear what you're asking here, that sentence is one independent sentence with **one subject** and **verb** combination. (Subject)We (verb) *can return.* (Subject) We (verb) *can exchange*. **We acts as the subject for both of the verbs.** *Items* is the **direct object**.

Comment: I thought one indepent sentence can have many main verbs

Comment: Yes one independent sentence can have many main verbs. This particular sentence has one subject, and that subject is doing two actions. That means there is only one subject for two verbs, or **one subject verb combination**.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one sentence here.  If you were to make two independent sentences with the same subject and object it would be:

1. We can return the purchased items.
2. We can exchange the purchased items.

The two verbs are joined to make one independent sentence.